# icons for Android

Tags: home-screen-shortcuts

I would like to assign some simple icons to Gmail label shortcuts, like an airplane for travel. Is there a convenient way to do this? Icon selection seems to go through the Gallery app now.

Comment: @gatoatigrado Are you trying to make icons within the GMail Android app itself? Or are you trying to make icons on your home screen that open the app to a particular label? Or something else?

Comment: The second -- set a homescreen shortcut icon.

Answer (score 3):

If you use [ADW Launcher](https://market.android.com/details?id=org.adw.launcher), you can create the label shortcut on your homescreen and then use icons from a [themepack](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.gfxandroid.honeycomb&feature=search_result) to customise the look of said shortcut.